# Want to Import data from one activity to another with a button

Tags: android

Web View activity is :

```
public class show extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.orderlink);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int restu = intent.getIntExtra("restu", 0);
        // myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodmart.com.bd/index.php?Theme=default&Base=Page&Script=MenuPage&id=556");


    switch(restu){

        case 1:
            myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodmart.com.bd/index.php?Theme=default&Base=Page&Script=MenuPage&id=556");

        case 2:
            myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodpanda.com/");

    }

    }
}
```

My main  activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    void Click(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.order1 :
                Intent p = new Intent(MainActivity.this, show.class);
                p.putExtra("restu",1);
                startActivity(p);
                break;
            case R.id.order2 :
                Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, show.class);
                q.putExtra("restu",2);
                startActivity(q);
        }




    }
}
```

[image]

I want to open different web from button click. where is the prob please help me..............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: initialize the button and set onClick on them. Also implement onClickListener on the class.

Comment: check out the problem and solution here http://pastebin.com/G3KEYzM4

Comment: Debug and check if onCreate of your show Activity is called or not. And what is the value of your restu variable in the Activity.

Comment: its not working brahmy adigopula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, add break in each case.

```
switch(restu){

    case 1:
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodmart.com.bd/index.php?Theme=default&Base=Page&Script=MenuPage&id=556");
        break;

    case 2:
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodpanda.com/");
        break;
    default:
        Log.d("what??", "something must be wrong")
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
        Button b,b2;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.order1); //add with button id
                b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.order2);
                b.setOnClickListener(this);
                b2.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.order1 :
            Intent p = new Intent(getBaseContext(), show.class);
            p.putExtra("restu",1);
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.order2 :
            Intent q = new Intent(getBaseContext(), show.class);
            q.putExtra("restu",2);
            startActivity(q);
            break;
             }
          }
}
```

change your main activity to this. and use `getBaseContext()`

Comment: I have changed MainActivity.this to getBaseContext() both will work

Comment: Please check it

Comment: wait i am checking .

Comment: b.setOnClickListener(this); //// in this line for "this" parameter showing error.

Comment: please copy the implementation from my code implements View.OnClickListener mainactivity line

Comment: this line red means you are not implenting its class

Answer (score 0):

Use break in each case . And implement on button click listener .Rest seems fine .

Comment: why? be specific.